# How can I search for all files that are not user writeable in unix using grep

Tags: files, permissions, find

I am trying to see all the files that are not user writeable. I know I can use the `ls` command to view all, but I wanted to have just the ones that are not user writeable. I am currently in unix and the find command will not work for me

Comment: @steeldriver Note that the user can't seem to use `-writable` with `find` which implies that they are not on Linux.  The answer in the duplicate is therefore unusable to them.

Comment: @steeldriver ... or they are mistyping the command.

Comment: -bash-3.2$ find . -type f ! -prem -u=w then the system responds with -bash-3.2$

Comment: @don_crissti I hear you. That's a good point.

Comment: @jameetbhatti `-prem` should be `-perm`.

Comment: sorry i did type -perm made a mistake when typing it over here

Answer (score 2):

With standard `find` (should work on any Unix system):

```
find . -type f ! -perm -u=w
```

This will find all files that are not writable by their owner.

With GNU `find` (default on Linux systems):

```
find . -type f ! -writable
```

The GNU variation will find files that *may be writable by the file's owner*, but not by the current user.

Comment: it keeps responding saying find: abd option -writable

Comment: @jameetbhatti What Unix are you using?  The second variation will only work with GNU `find` (the default find on Linux). Other Unices sometimes has this installed as `gfind`.

Comment: I am currently using a program called putty which puts me in the bash shell

Comment: @jameetbhatti Ok, is the machine that you are connecting to running Linux or or some other Unix? The first command should work regardless.

Comment: still brings an error is there anyway i can do it using grep?

Comment: @jameetbhatti Are you still using the second command? That will not work if you don't have GNU `find`. The first command should work on any Unix. What do you type and what is the error?

Comment: it will execute the command then nothing will come back in return. It will just go right back to -bash-3.2$

Comment: @jameetbhatti Then there are no files that are not user writable in or below the current directory.

Comment: there are about 15 files that are all user writable i used the ls -l command to check that

Comment: @jameetbhatti Sure, and you asked about finding files that were _not_ user writable.